# Derivative of $||x||$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, $r=||x||=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots + x_n^2}$

and let $u(x_1, \dots, x_n) = f(r), x\neq(0,0,...,0)$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)^2
 = (f'(r))^2
$$

How can I show this equality? I need help.

Comment: Use $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\dfrac{du}{dr}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

By the chain rule we have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=f'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}$$

and $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^{2}+...+x_n^{2}}}\quad \text{for $i=1,...n$}$$